# How to use data structures to find a person with the given eye color?

Tags: python

this is my homework:

> Write a program to find the person with a given eye color. This is the
> data structure to use. The user of your program will input the eye
> color. Please put the following into the appropriate data structure.
>
> Name     Age   Eye Color
>
> Joe          20      Blue
>
> Jane        21       Green
>
> Jill           19       Black
>
> Bill           24      Brown

And this is what I've done

```
name = ["joe", "jane", "jill", "bill"];
age = [20, 21, 19, 24];
eyeColor = ["blue", "green", "black", "brown"];

print (name = age = eyeColor)
```

But it doesn't work. I am new to Python and did as much research as I can, so I decided to ask on here. I am not done researching and I will try to figure it out, but in the meantime I will ask on here.

I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: What exactly do you think `print(name=age=eyeColor)` should do?

Comment: @ScottHunter I don't know. I thought it would do something like: joe = 20 = blue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is loop through the eyeColor and then simply print the matching ones with let's say green. Replace green with a variable with the user input(convert everything to a similar case tolower). If you need one matching add a break at the end of the if.

```
name = ["joe", "jane", "jill", "bill"];
age = [20, 21, 19, 24];
eyeColor = ["blue", "green", "black", "brown"];
for index in range(len(eyeColor)):
    if eyeColor[index] == "green":
        print(name[index],age[index],eyeColor[index])
```

Comment: I completed the code using yours and I finally figured out how to do it and how data structures work!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a dataset with three columns(name, age, eye color respectively)? And the user will input the eye color, you need to output the corresponding name and age? Correct me if I am wrong.

Is the eye color of every person unique? If so, following what you already did, you can use the index of `eyeColor` to get the corresponding name and age.

Comment: I'm so sorry for the stupid question, but what does that mean and how do I do it? I am really sorry again for the dumb question. I am clueless. Also, yes. You are correct.

Comment: There are many ways that can do it depending on different scenarios. If the `eyeColor` is unique in you data(no two person have same eyeColor), you can use a [dictionary structure](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html), and use `eyeColor` as key, and `name, age` as value.

Answer (score 0):

In your case I would suggest you using classes. In your example, it should look like this:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age, eyeColor):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.eye = eyeColor

Joe = Person('joe', 20, 'Blue')
Jane = Person('jane', 21, 'Green')
Jill = Person('jill', 19, 'Black')
Bill = Person('bill', 24, 'Brown')
```

If you want to print someone properties you can do it for example (for Joe):

```
print(Joe.name, Joe.age, Joe.eye)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your response to @Ruoyu Guo's question

The first thing you should do is figure out the index of the column with the eye color. You can do this by iterating the list:

```
target_color = ""  # get this passed in
target_ix = None # what you're searching for

# enumerate proves an index and value for each member of an iterable 
for ix, color in enumerate(eyeColor):
   if eyeColor = target_color:
      target_ix = ix # assign your target value
      break # exit the loop - no need to continue because you've found the column
```

Then you use this index to reference the column values in the other lists:

```
print(f"{name[target_ix]} is {age[target_ix]} years old and has {target_color} eyes")
```